# How to have build manager for SVN

Tags: svn

I have task to build EAR file automatically from last committed files on SVN.
Actually we work on several projects and every developer will commit it own file on SVN. My task is to find a way to automatically unskilled person can create EAR from last committed files on each project.
Actually I don't have any idea about this and how can I start to handle it.

Comment: How do you currently perform your builds? Do you use ANT or Maven?

Comment: I use ANT in my local system, actually I use it to deploy mt local project on my local  Weblogic

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of tools out there that do this and more depending on how far you want to go. The first thing you need to know is how you currently do your builds. If you use a tool like ANT or Maven, then this shouldn't be that difficult. I would look at a continuous integration server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). I have used both and I personally thought that TeamCity helped you get going a little faster. CI servers can do a lot for you by automating build and test execution, sending emails etc. If you are looking for a more quick and dirty approach you can use an [SVN post commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html), to build your application every time a commit is completed. You should be able to find a decent example online and if you look at your svn repository (on the server not the client). you should see a file at [path to your repo]/hooks/post_comit.tmpl . That gives you the basic template for the hook script all you need to do is remove the .tmpl off the end and it will start executing after every commit.

Comment: Thanks mmilleruva, are they compatible with SVN ? I means could they user SVN as repository to fetch last committed files and jars to build EAR file ?

Comment: Yes Jenkins and Team City both compatible with svn. You would configure the build server with the location of your repository and then specify the path to your ANT script. The server will regularly poll the svn repo to find changes. When it detects a change it will execute your ANT script.

Comment: I Also found Hudson which look it's special for JAVA how is it ? Good to work on that or not, by the way I found Team City is not free and I should pay for it .

Comment: Hudson is the older version of Jenkins. Also, TeamCity has an enterprise edition that is not free, but there is a professional edition that is free: http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/index.html

Comment: @soheilz92, if this was helpful please approve my answer